# How know exactly what is the correct order of the dataset using set_name function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Recently I plotted a boxplot with 3 different datasets.
The plot is fine. But when I use the function set_names, I set the data in this order: "S", "M", and "E", instead the order is not the same.
Here is the code:

```
df <- 
  list(df_1v, df_2v, df_3v) %>% 
  set_names(c("S", "M", "E")) %>% 
  map_dfr(bind_rows, .id = "df") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-df)
```

So, here I set the order of the data frames that I use in the same order that when setting the function set_names.
However, this is the plot:
[image]

This plot shows the inverted order: "E", "M", and "S".
How can I know if the data is in the correct order without seeing each value of the data frame (the data is enormous)?
There is a function to know the exact order?

Only in case do you need it, here is the code for the boxplot:

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = name, y = value), 
               fill = "blue",
               color = "blue",
               alpha = 0.2,
               notch = T,
               notchwidth = 0.8)+
  facet_wrap(~df, nrow = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, however, with your idea there is no data frame, I mean df_1v, df_2v, and df3v are my data frame. What happens with them? @RonakShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code -

```
library(tidyverse)

list(df_1v, df_2v, df_3v) %>% 
  set_names(c("S", "M", "E")) %>% 
  map_dfr(bind_rows, .id = "df") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-df) %>%
  mutate(df = factor(df, unique(df))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = name, y = value), 
               fill = "blue",
               color = "blue",
               alpha = 0.2,
               notch = T,
               notchwidth = 0.8) +
  facet_wrap(~df, nrow = 1)
```

The order of plots is controlled by levels of factor variable in the data.  By using `factor(df, unique(df))` the levels are assigned based on their occurrence in the data so we get the order as we specified in `set_names` i.e `c("S", "M", "E")`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It looks fine (plot), I have been reading the documentation for the mutate function, and I have only one question, I suppose that this function creates a new variable but not new values in the data frame? @Ronak

Comment: `mutate` can create new variable or update existing ones. In this case, we are updating an existing one by changing the character values to factor. The order of plots is controlled by levels of factor variable in the data by using `factor(df, unique(df))` the levels are assigned based on their occurrence in the data so we get the order as we specified in `set_names` i.e `c("S", "M", "E")`